# Does CGImageRelease() free UIImage's memory?

Tags: uiimage, cgimage

I have the following code:

```
UIImage *originalImage;
CGImageRef cgImage = [originalImage CGImage];
```

I know that *CGImage* is a read-only property of *UIImage* class.
Does the line

```
CGImageRelease(cgImage)
```

free *originalImage*'s memory?

I'm tracing down a bug in my program and this line seems to be a hot candidate if I'm trying to access *originalImage* later.

Thanks,
Stefan

Answer (score 8):

I've found the answer myself: Because the call

```
CGImageRef img = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"pic.png"] CGImage];
```

does not contain one of the words *create*, *copy* or *alloc*, I am not responsible for freeing this memory.